# Angular-indexedDB: Issues with Firefox

Tags: angularjs, indexeddb

I'm using AngularJS and IndexedDB in my application. There is a really nice tool on GitHub that contains an AngularJS module for IndexedDB. The library is called Angular-indexedDB and is available [here](https://github.com/webcss/angular-indexedDB).

I'm facing issues when I try to open my existing application using Firefox version 31 (the latest).

When I open the console I see the following message:

```
TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked the angular-indexedDB and implemented the solution using AngularJS $window instead. I also sent a pull request, hopefully it will be integrated soon.

I completely removed the first two lines that used global namespace. Then, I moved the implementation to the **$get** function for the indexedDB provider. Which now looks like follow:

```
    module.$get = ['$q', '$rootScope', '$window', function($q, $rootScope, $window) {

       if(!('indexedDB' in $window)) {
             $window.indexedDB = $window.mozIndexedDB || $window.webkitIndexedDB || $window.msIndexedDB;
       }

       var IDBKeyRange = $window.IDBKeyRange || $window.mozIDBKeyRange || $window.webkitIDBKeyRange || $window.msIDBKeyRange;
       ...
```

If you look [here](https://github.com/alansouzati/angular-indexedDB/blob/master/src/indexeddb.js), you can find the full implementation. Just replace your existing script by this one and it should work fine in Firefox 31.

Comment: Good news! The merge request has been approved and applied to the project.

Answer (score 0):

To fixed the problem I had to change the code for this library (I will send the pull request soon).

To get it working in Firefox replace line 9 from this [JS file](https://github.com/webcss/angular-indexedDB/blob/master/src/indexeddb.js) by this:

```
if(!('indexedDB' in window)) {
    var indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
}
```

The fix is simple enough. If indexedDB is not in window it means that I can create the first one.

Comment: As I did not write this library, I'm not sure. From what I understand about this code, I believe this is important because some version of browsers seem to have different var names to host IndexedDB (e.g mozIndexedDB). Would you have any suggested fix? If so, could you please post as an answer?

Comment: Actually you are right. We can move this to $get to not pollute the global namespace. I will post another answer with my solution.